# PHP validation booleans using filter_var

Tags: php, validation, boolean, filter-var

I'm using `filter_var` to validate boolean values but I did not expect it to not recognize `FALSE`. Why does this happen?

`filter_var(FALSE, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE)`

returns

`null`

Comment: you want to validate the bool FALSE?

Comment: read this: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Validating-Boolean-Values-and-Float-Numbers-with-Filters-in-PHP-5/1/

Comment: well yes, I'm wondering why `TRUE` returns TRUE but `FALSE` returns null

Comment: Looks buggy. `filter_var(false, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE)` is `null`, `filter_var(0, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE)` is `false`. I'm on 5.3.3

Comment: You could avoid ambiguity by using a `(bool)` cast on the result: `$val = FALSE; $val = (bool) filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);`

Comment: @powtac Are you sure, it returns `true`? On my machine `filter_var(false, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)` (w/o `FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE`) is `false`.

Comment: I get the same result (false)

Comment: @DerVO Sorry guys, I got `false` as well. Deleted my wrong comment.

Comment: Found this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49510 -- unfortunately, by the date of the report, there doesn't seem to be any rush to fixing this

Answer (score 7):

`filter_var` is new as of PHP 5.2.  You've run into a known bug:  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49510
Feel free to vote on or comment on that bug.

You're trying to do something like this:

```
$v = filter_var($v, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE)
```

There are a number of cheap workarounds like this:

```
$v = $v===FALSE ? FALSE : filter_var($v, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE)
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like this is actually how it's supposed to work, strangely enough (yes, my mind was blown by that). From https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51344

> This is going to sound insane when you've looked at the underlying
>   filter code, but this is actually correct according to the
>   documentation: the default behaviour of filter_input() is to return
>   NULL for non-existent inputs and false when validation fails, and
>   FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE simply flips that behaviour to false for
>   non-existent inputs and NULL on validation failure. (No, I don't have
>   a clue where that would be useful either, and the name of the flag is
>   unfortunate in the filter_input() context, since it implies that NULL
>   wouldn't normally be returned. It makes more sense when used with
>   filter_var(), which doesn't have the non-existent input case.)
>
> [table omitted due to SO formatting]
>
> I'll pop a comment into the filter_input() and filter_input_array()
>   implementations to note that this is by design, even though the code
>   does kind of look wrong.
>
> Closing Won't Fix.

Answer (score 1):

This was the behaviour when `filter_var` was first introduced with version 5.2 and resolved at some point after 5.4 as is seen by this https://3v4l.org/Cv1MZ

Starting from version 5.4 this is what happens:

```
var_dump(filter_var(FALSE, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE));
```

> bool(false)

which makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

> Returns true for "1", "true", "on" and "yes". Returns false otherwise.

Anything different than the values mentioned above is considered falsy. This is not to test if a variable is actually a boolean like with `typeof` or `is_bool()`, but more like a mean to test if the input comming from the user (usually an `<input type="checkbox">` form) is `truthy/falsy`.

The behavior of this function could be understand as `let it go through if it's correct` rather than a mean to test the type of a variable (we have lots of other functions for this). Exemple :

```
filter_var('435345', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)
```

The type is a string, but the result is not true/false as the intention is not to validate the type. So an `int` would be returned (let go through).